# Live streaming in SP2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to do a live streaming with unlimited participant can joined in SP2010 ?

Comment: SharePoint Server has no live video streaming functionality.

Comment: Is there any other solution that I can do?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Server products do not provide the function of live streaming.

You should be looking for social networking service or communication platform like **Yammer** or **Teams**.

References: [Live events in Yammer.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/yammer/manage-yammer-groups/yammer-live-events) / [Broadcast a live event in classic Yammer using Teams.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/broadcast-a-live-event-in-classic-yammer-using-teams-333a5ea6-c73e-4717-8c53-7ea8f8de2724)

Yammer Enterprise also provides integration with SharePoint Server in case you need collaboration between these two products: [Integrate Yammer with on-premises SharePoint Server environments.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/integrate-yammer-with-on-premises-sharepoint-server-environments)